# Integrating RequireJS into OSGi server

Tags: osgi, requirejs, amd, js-amd, eclipse-virgo

**Note: Please don't be intimidated by the word "OSGi."**

I am integrating RequireJS on an OSGi-based Virgo server environment (though the details are irrelevant). With an OSGi configuration, I have a root "OSGi bundle" that has JavaScript that needs to set up the main view. Then there are sub-bundles that rely on the root, each with their own JavaScript that needs to be executed.

I have RequireJS running well in the root bundle, with a "main" file that sets up the main view.

**Questions:** However, I don't know how best to initialize the execution of sub-bundles. Should I add a second `<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>` tag, this time in the sub-bundle to kick off its JavaScript execution? Should I simply import the main JavaScript file as normal in the sub-bundles?

Comment: Can you add the path when you require the object; subfolder/myobject?

Comment: The root path would be "resources/js/main.js" and an example of a particular sub-bundle would be "sub-bundle/resources/js/main.js".

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize the execution of sub-bundles"? From your answer below it looks like you mean "initialize the paths configuration"?

Comment: I'm not intimidated by OSGi. It's the JavaScript bit that scares me!

Comment: @explunit There are two executions that need to be kicked off: the main framework and the sub-bundles (which are consumers of the framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up the framework's main JavaScript resources with the following tag in the root bundle:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="<c:url value="require.js" />"></script>
```

. . . with "js/main.js" being:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
  // main script goes here . . .
})
```

With the above in the root bundle, sub-bundles simply invoke their own JavaScript with:

```
<script>require(['sub-bundle/js/script.js'])</script>
```

**So the answer to my question is simply: Use the `require` function in sub-bundles!**

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that I found works, even though it is an ugly and unwanted solution, is to create a global object in the root OSGi bundle that stores the paths relevant to the root. Then sub-bundles can extend their own paths onto this object and reinitialize RequireJS.

Example in root bundle:

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    // root bundle paths go here . . .
  }
};

require(config.requirejs);
```

Example in sub-bundle:

```
$.extend(true, {
  paths: {
    // sub-bundle paths go here . . .
  }
}, config);

require(config.requirejs);
```

But I don't like having to (seemingly to me) reinitialize RequireJS. Hopefully someone will know of a better solution.